# In VBA Excel, code to pass value from userform based on certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help for a vba code.

Data is on the same worksheet.

I created a userform that contains a combobox and a text box. The values in the combobox are names stored in sheet1.range("A1:A300"). The user enters a phone number in the textbox.

I struggle creating a code where I could pass the textbox value next to the name choosen by the user in the combobox. The textbox value would be stored in column B.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` should be pretty useful.

Comment: Something like `Sheet1.Range("A1:A300").Find(yourcombobox.value).Offset(,1).value = yourtextbox.value`. Although probably good to break that out for validation that something was found, and that a phone number exists, etc.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I tried adding the code "Sheet1.Range("A1:A300").Find(yourcombobox.value).Offset(,1).value = yourtextbox.value", but i get error 91 "object variable". Of course, I entered the exact names of my combo and text boxes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Set Rng = Range("A1:A300")
Set c = Rng.Find(ListBox1.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
c.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set Rng = Range("A1:A300")
ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Rng)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. I still get error 91 with the code "c.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value" highlighted.

Comment: @RED, Please tell me what is the name of your textbox ? what is the name of your listbox ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out why I had the error. The contents of range(a1:a300) were actually formula, i.e. a concatenation of two cells. The error disappeared when I changed the formula into absolute values. Thanks again.

Comment: Now that I had it figured, I wonder if I could bother you with one question: Is there a way to  temporarily change the formula into absolute values while the code is running, then revert the contents into formula after the code is executed?

Comment: Please try to change this `Set c = Rng.Find(ListBox1.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)` to `Set c = Rng.Find(ListBox1.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)`

Comment: Thanks too. Glad I can help.